# Simple xkcd comic downloader

Tags: haskell, json, http, web-scraping

I'd really appreciate some harsh/constructive criticism of what I would consider as my first program in Haskell.  The program should download all of the xkcd comics into a folder in the current directory.

I basically just threw the kitchen sink at it, using anything I found remotely interesting in RWH and on the Haskell wiki, so I'm 99% sure most of it is unnecessary or overkill.  I tried using most popular libraries I could find.
I wasn't clear on how to handle errors, how to deal with the filesystem efficiently, and how to use Text.JSON correctly.

[hpaste link](http://hpaste.org/46951/xkcd)

```
    {-# Language PackageImports #-}
module Main where

import System.FilePath (takeFileName, (</>))
import System.IO 
import System.Environment
import System.Posix.User
import System.Directory
import Control.Monad (liftM, forM_, replicateM_)
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Data.List (delete)
import Network.HTTP
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L
import "mtl" Control.Monad.Error
import Network.URI (parseURI)
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Exception
import qualified Network.Stream as Stream (Result) 
import Control.Arrow
import Text.JSON

----------------------------------------------------------------------
main = do
  dir <- makeComicDir
  putStrLn $ "Created " ++ dir
  Right json <- xkcdFetchJSON Current
  let curNum = xkcdGetNumber json "num"
      comics = take curNum $ iterate (subtract 1) curNum
  putStrLn $ "Downloading " ++ (show $ length comics) ++ " comics..."
  comicQueue <- newTChanIO
  atomically $ forM_ (ComicNumber <$> comics) $ writeTChan comicQueue
  workers <- newTVarIO 8
  replicateM_ 8  . forkIO $ worker comicQueue workers dir
  waitFor workers
  putStrLn "DONE"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
data ComicNumber = Current | ComicNumber Int deriving (Show)

getReq = fmap (mkRequest GET) . parseURI

getRequestE = maybe (throwError "invalid url") return . getReq

tryRequest :: Request_String
           -> IO (Either IOException (Stream.Result (Response String)))

tryRequest = try . simpleHTTP

simpleHttpE request = do
  response <- liftIO $ tryRequest request
  case response of
    Left  err -> throwError $ show err
    Right rsp -> return rsp

getResponseBodyE = either (throwError.show) (return.rspBody)

fetchHtmlA = Kleisli getRequestE >>>
             Kleisli simpleHttpE >>>
             Kleisli getResponseBodyE

fetchHTMLBody url = runErrorT $ runKleisli fetchHtmlA url
----------------------------------------------------------------------
xkcd = "http://xkcd.com/"

xkcdJSONUrl Current          = xkcd ++ "info.0.json"
xkcdJSONUrl (ComicNumber n)  = xkcd ++ show n ++ "/info.0.json"

xkcdFetchJSON :: ComicNumber -> IO (Either String String)
xkcdFetchJSON num = runErrorT $ runKleisli fetchHtmlA $ xkcdJSONUrl num

xkcdComicUrl :: ComicNumber -> IO String
xkcdComicUrl num = do
  Right jstr <- xkcdFetchJSON num
  let (Ok (JSObject jobj)) = decode jstr
      (Ok img) = valFromObj "img" jobj
  return img

xkcdGetNumber :: String -> String -> Int
xkcdGetNumber jstr key = 
  let (Ok (JSObject jobj)) = decode jstr
      (Ok jval) = valFromObj key jobj
  in jval

----------------------------------------------------------------------
getImgName = takeFileName

downloadComic dir num = do
  url <- xkcdComicUrl num 
  let (ComicNumber n) = num
      name = (show n) ++ "_" ++ getImgName url
      path = dir </> name
  comic <- fetchHTMLBody url
  case comic of
    Left  err -> putStrLn $ "ERROR: " ++ show err
    Right img -> do
      file <- openBinaryFile path WriteMode
      hPutStr file img
      hClose file
      putStrLn $ "Saving " ++ name

makeComicDir = do 
  homedir <- getHomeDirectory
  let imgdir = homedir </> ".xkcd"
  createDirectory imgdir
  return imgdir

worker jobs alive dir = work
  where quit = atomically $ readTVar alive >>= writeTVar alive . (subtract 1)
        cont = do job@(ComicNumber n) <- atomically $ readTChan jobs
                  if' (n == 404) work $ downloadComic dir job >> work
        work = (atomically $ isEmptyTChan jobs) >>= \x -> if' x quit cont

waitFor alive = atomically $ readTVar alive >>= check . (==0)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
if' :: Bool -> a -> a -> a
if' True x _  = x
if' False _ y = y
```

Comment: simpleHttpE seems to be converting Either to an IO Exception, right after tryRequest converts the IO exception to Either. Is this not redundant?

Comment: `comics = reverse [1..curNum]`

Comment: The Kleisli stuff is just Kleisli composition, isn't it?  Use `<=<`.

Answer (score 11):

Looks pretty good. You're getting on top of stuff nicely. Some criticism:

- don't use package imports
- write type signatures for top level functions
- write comments!
- thread design looks good.
- don't use `if'`. Haskell has `if` already.
- Kleisli needs documentation. Starting to go overboard at this point.
- don't mix too many concepts in one program: the code won't be maintainable.

Comment: Thanks. Some of the type signatures were awfully long so I wasn't sure whether to include them or not.

Comment: Perhaps write type synonyms for the major part of the design?

Comment: I really like using if as a function instead of a keyword. It's more intuitive for me and the syntax seems more readable. Is there any if function in the standard libraries?

Comment: @Anonymous if there were, you would be able to find it by putting [its type into Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Bool+-%3E+a+-%3E+a+-%3E+a). So I guess not.

Comment: Haskell's if-then-else can be a bit of a straightjacket sometimes -- such as when you don't want an "else" clause. There's a whole discussion about if' here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/If-then-else

Comment: What's wrong with the PackageImports extension?  Apparently, this was needed to work around the conflicting packages mtl and transformers (though I don't think they conflict anymore these days).